# How to achieve this water splash animation for any solid object ( suzanne for ex)?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am really trying to understand mantaflow and water simulation in blender and I want to make a fluid animation that throws water on an object in blender (kind of like the 3D splash effect you might see in product animations) I would really like a perspective or general overview on how would this be kind of achieved.

[image]

Something like this. Would really appreciate any tutorials or guides that point me exactly on achieving this effect.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hello, you need to make the razor an Effector in the physics panel

Comment: yes but how do I achieve that effect flowing through one part of the scene to the other, and the various other settings like flow and density and stuff

Comment: CG Geek has made a tutorial about a ball splash here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVwfEHtLiyI

Comment: although you don't want to read that: experimenting with simulations is essential to understand how it works and what settings change what behaviours. This site is not for tutorials, but for very specific problems where you are stuck at.

Comment: i would start with a quick liquid simulation, add a new object with collision and give the flow object some starting speed. then check how it looks and change settings until you like it. of course high resolution looks better but takes more time. maybe you also want to reduce time scale to see the splash better.

Comment: I did follow a tutorial before, but the fluid was very erratic and didn't move the way I wanted it to, I think I'll take the below answer as a guide, and as you said, experiment with it till I find something that sticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a simple example to start with:

[image]

[image]

[image]

general hint: water simulation should be rendered in cycles - looks 10x better than in eevee.

Comment: Yes but you've done is for a shampoo, he's talking about a razor

Comment: so should i delete the answer? 